# How to cache common (for all pixels) variables in ShaderLab?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, shaderlab

Suppose I have the following shader:

```
Shader "Sprites/X"
{
    Properties
    {
        [HideInInspector] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "black" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            // bla bla

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float a = calculateA();
                float b = calculateB();
                .
                .
                .
                float z = calculateZ();

                // Here the values above mix with x-y position of the pixel
                // and then return a color
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code I need to calculate the values of the variables `a` - `z` from the related functions `calculateA()` -  `calculateZ()` (it's just a generalization example). Suppose these functions are complex and that they depend from other properties of the shader that change in each frame, instead of the pixel itself. We know that the complex functions are computed every time for each pixel.

There is a way to "cache" these values to avoid the calculation each time for each pixel? In every frame their values is the same for all the pixels.

Currently I'm solving the problem by setting the values in the C# script with:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("a", calculateA());
.
.
.
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("z", calculateZ());
```

but i prefer to mantain the shader and the C# script code separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's exactly how you'd do it :)

It depends on why exactly you'd want to avoid using C#

- If said method is computed solely out of constants then the compiler
  would optimize it away.
- If the method has few predictable outcomes
  you could pre-compute them into an array declared in the shader itself, or set once from code instead of every frame.
- If there are a lot of those predictable outcomes you could look into baking them
  into a texture, or if you can use a modern GPU, into structured
  buffers.